# awk: dont Display matched regex (multiline)

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I want to use a Regex that find all lines in text except the lines that I passed with Regex. I have found a useful code here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389421/awk-display-matched-regex-multiline)`awk '/.*test.*/{f=1}f;/end/{f=0}' myFile`. I want to use it contrariwise.

I mean I don't want to see the lines between **test** and **end**, but I want to see other lines.

I want to do this on a **Linux** environment.

How can I negative these `AWK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like this

```
awk '/test/ {f=1} !f; /end/ {f=0}' file
```

It will print all lines until it find `test`, then start print again after `end` is found.

Answer (score 1):

To see all lines between `first` and `end`, inclusive:

```
awk '/first/,/end/'
```

To invert that:

```
awk '/first/,/end/{next}1'
```

(Slightly more readably, for the second example: `awk '/first/,/end/{next}{print}'`. The version above depends on awk's default action `{print}`; `1` is the equivalent of `true`.)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is more appropriate for this:

```
sed '/first/,/end/d'
```

will delete all lines between and including a line matching the pattern `first` until the first line matching the pattern `end`.